# Remove border from splash screen in Visual Studio

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

The title here pretty much explains it all. I am working in Visual Studio 2012, I have created a transparent splash screen in photoshop. I made the background of the control white and set the transparency key to white as well. So the background is now transparent, but I still have a border around the entire image/splash screen.

The only problem I am running into is getting rid of the border. I can live with it if I have to, but I really want to see it without that border. :) Thanks in advance.

Comment: For this kind of problem, you really need to create a walk through (starting from File->New Project) of a sample that demonstrates the problem. If you *can't* create such a walk through, trying to produce it should *hopefully* help you to isolate the issue. If you *can* create the walkthrough, at least everyone can examine the issue separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set property formborderstyle to none (or undecorated)